# How to handle and have two types of users in django

Tags: python, django, database

I'm working on a project that should handle two types of users.
normal users and teachers.

I created one major model. actually I extended AbstractUser built-in django model and added some other fields to it. one of extra fields is is_teacher that is BooleanField and default is False. for users registration I created ModelForm from model User that I extended before. and while registration I set default value for is_teacher = False to specify that this user is normal user. and for teachers registration is_teacher = True. This is ok for both users and teachers login and redirecting them to their panel. but issue is coming after that. I need third model for something else. I need to have ManyToMany field in third model with NORMAL users and TEACHERS; both of them but I have only one model. actually I didn't separate users and teachers models from each other. because of that I don't know how to specify ManyToMany relation with users model and ManyToMany relation with teachers. There is something that I can do (maybe) is creating two types of models one for users and one for teachers and in respect of those two models I have to create two login page and two profile and two registration and then maybe I can create third model as I told you. The question is: Is that true to have two model one for users and one for teachers... ? Is there any solution except of this. Im new to django explain it clearly, please.

Model Form for third_model:

```
class RequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ThirdModel
        fields = ("height", "age", "address")

        widgets = {
            "user": "hidden"
        }
```

View for saving data in ThirdModel:

```
@login_required
def request_plan(request):
    form = RequestForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = request.POST.get('username')
        form.save(commit=False)
        form.save()

    context = {
        "request_form": form
    }
    return render(request, "plan/request.html", context)


 class User(AbstractUser):
SEX_CHOICES = (
    ("male", "Male"),
    ("female", "Female")
)
sex         = models.CharField(max_length=6,    choices=SEX_CHOICES)
bio         = models.CharField(max_length=100)
is_coach    = models.BooleanField(max_length=100, default=False)
```

Comment: What is the problem for adding 2 M2M fields both for User in your third model? one for teachers and another to normal. What difficulty you forsee?

Comment: thanks. as I told you I didn’t sparate model **User**. I saved both (teachers and normal) users in model **User**. So how can I define M2M in third model? I don’t have model **Teacher**. Only model User.

Comment: Please see my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to do as following:

```
class ThirdModel(models.Model):
    teachers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='third_model_teachers')
    normal_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='third_model_normals')
```

You have 2 users `user1` and `user2`
You can add first as teacher:

```
third_model.teachers.add(user1)
third_model.normal_users.add(user2)
```

To get all third_model where user a teacher.

```
user1.third_model_teachers.all()
```

To get all third_models where user a normal users

```
user2.third_model_normals.all()
```

If you have any questions please comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another model for Teachers with a OneToOne field to User, and keep teacher only data in that model. You won't need to create different login methods with this approach, login operations could run on base User model, and you can use the Teacher model for teacher specific operations.

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following models

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).